# Proof verification: the angle subtended by a chord can never be 90 degrees

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, circles

I couldn't find any sources of this online, so I would like to ask if what I'm proposing below is correct, or if a similar theorem has been proven before.

We know that  the angle subtended by the diameter of a circle is always $90^\circ$ (Thales' Theorem).  In the image below, the angle at any point $C$ on the highlighted arc will be $90^\circ$ if $AB$ is the diameter.

[image]

Suppose now that $AB$ wasn't the diameter. Is there a theorem that says that there does not exist a point $C$ on the circle such that the angle at $C$ is $90^\circ$?

[image]

I will use a diagram to explain my reasoning.

[image]

My reasoning is as follows: if you could find me a point in the minor arc highlighted above such that $\angle ACB=90^\circ$, then if you 'push' AB down to the diameter to get DE, the $\angle DCE < \angle ACB$, which is a contradiction of Thales' Theorem!

A similar reasoning can be used to explain for the major arc of the circle.

I'm posting this on MSE as I want to know:

1. Is this a valid proof? I know it's not rigorous but is the way I'm going about it correct?
2. Has this already been proven? Is there a name for this theorem or is it simply an obvious corollary of Thales' theorem (that I wasn't aware of)?

Comment: Thus ist implied by the *Central Angle Theorem*, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle

Comment: This converse does not appear to be called Thales' theorem (i.e. it's Thales' theorem is not an if and only if statement), but [it definitely has been proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem#Converse). If you want to turn your thoughts into proof, you might want to explain why $\angle DCE$ is *strictly* less than $\angle ACB$.

Comment: Cool, I guess it's a consequence of Thales' theorem I never taught of until now. For some context, I was trying to prove this for the theorem that if you have a tangent and normal line to some point on a curve, P, then for every 2 points you can pick, one from the tangent and one from normal line, there must exist a circle passing through those 2 points and P with diameter being the distance between the 2 points you have picked.

Comment: No matter whether $AB$ is a chord or a diameter, $\angle ACB$ does not depend on the choice of $C$ (except for whether $C$ appears on one side of $AB$ or the other; if $C$ and $C'$ appear on opposite sides of $AB$, then $\angle ACB+\angle AC'B=180^\circ$).

Answer (score 0):

not the prettiest solution but perhaps this helps:

[image]

basically I assumed that we have input of 90 degree angle without assuming we are at the center, and we got that $y=x$ thus it indeed must be the center - proving back Thales' theorem